# Error when playing sound with phoneGap

Tags: android, html, audio, cordova

Hi i'm trying to add sound to a game buttons and different copmponent i'm using this code from phoneGap site and it works fine when i test it :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Media Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        playAudio("http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3");
    }

    // Audio player
    //
    var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;

    // Play audio
    //
    function playAudio(src) {
        // Create Media object from src
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();

        // Update my_media position every second
        if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                // get my_media position
                my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    // Pause audio
    // 
    function pauseAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop audio
    // 
    function stopAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.stop();
        }
        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback 
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    // 
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="btn large"  
  onclick="playAudio('http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-   
   _rockGuitar.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="pauseAudio();">Pause Playing Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="stopAudio();">Stop Playing Audio</a>
    <p id="audio_position"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when i use it im my own code an error is generated here's my code :

html:

```
    <section id="popup">
    <div id="popup-bg">
    </div>
    <div id="popup-box">
        <div id="popup-box-content">
    **<p><a id="gamePlay" class="gameReset button"  href="">Play</a></p>**
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

javaScript:

```
   var ui = $("#gameUI");
   var uiIntro = $("#popup");


   //Wait for PhoneGap to load//
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


     // PhoneGap is ready
         //
        function onDeviceReady() {
          playAudio("http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3");
         }

      //Audio player//
    var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;



   $(function(){
  init();
      });


    function init() {
        uiComplete.hide();
        uiCards.hide();
        playGame = false;

        **uiPlay.click(function(e) { //this is the button i want to play             
                                                  //sound after clicking it 
        e.preventDefault();

            playAudio('http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3');
                    //uiIntro.hide();
                    //startGame();
                });**
        }

         .....


    /****Audio Part***********/
   // Play audio//
    function playAudio(src) {
        // Create Media object from src
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();

        // Update my_media position every second
        if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                // get my_media position
                my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    // Pause audio
    // 
    function pauseAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop audio
    // 
    function stopAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.stop();
        }
        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback 
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    // 
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }
```

i didn't put the whole code only the part of sound.
I'm getting this error after clicking on the uiPlay button :

```
   05-09 16:38:35.580: E/Web Console(521): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Media    
   at file:///android_asset/www/js/dinopairs6.js:196
```

Any idea please ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This's me again i just forget to add the script tag including phonegep.js in my HTML file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

Hope this Help other one :)